# Re. copying movie from USB card reader back to my camera

Tags: video

I have a Canon Digital Ixus 860IS.  I originally copied a short movie from my camera onto the computer via a USB card reader and then copied it back onto the camera via the same USB card reader along with some photos.  The photos have copied back fine but the movie, although it's showing to have copied, can't be seen.  Any reason for this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The camera will expect the movie to be in the correct place and have the correct name.

Is there a separate folder for movies? If so, have you put the movie back there?